# Using Combine from Swift package

Tags: xcode, xcode11

**Platform:** macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A512f)
**Xcode:** 11 beta 3

The following code that uses the Combine framework works fine in an iOS app project.

```
import Combine

func test() {
    [1, 2, 3, 4].publisher()
        .sink { (num) in
            print(num)
    }
}
```

But the same code in a Swift package project shows this error:

```
'publisher()' is only available in macOS 10.15 or newer
```

Do I have to add dependency to Combine in `Package.swift` or configure some other settings?

Comment: It all is still in beta, that's the only reason I see

Comment: Tried it on macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta 6 and XCode 11 beta 6, and changed the code to ```[1, 2, 3, 4].publisher.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })```. It ran without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You should open your project with projectName.xcodeproj and not package.swift
If you don't have the projectName.xcodeproj make it with 'make xcodeproj'